# Why doesn't Raiserror get invoked?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, subquery

If I have this block inside a transaction:

```
Begin Try
  Begin Transaction tran


    Declare @ExpiryDate varchar(100)
        Set @ExpiryDate= (Select NewExpiryDate from NIT n where n.NITNo= @NitNo)
        IF(CONVERT(DATE,@ExpiryDate)) < convert(date,getdate())
        Begin
                RAISERROR('error occurred', 16,1);
                return;
        End

  Commit Transaction tran
End Try
Begin Catch
                select ERROR_MESSAGE()

                Rollback transaction tran1
End Catch
```

...it reaches the catch block but an error is never raised. It never throws error. Why?

Comment: If there is an error in the `try` block and the `catch` block is executed then why would it `RaIsError`? That statement isn't in the `catch` block. Aside: It also looks like you're using [nested transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189336(v=sql.105)). They might not behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it as:

```
Begin Try
  Begin Transaction tran;

  Declare @ExpiryDate DATE =(Select NewExpiryDate from NIT where n.NITNo= @NitNo);

  IF @ExpiryDate < convert(date,getdate())
      RAISERROR('error occurred', 16,1);

  Commit Transaction tran;
End Try
Begin Catch
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 Rollback transaction tran1;
   THROW;  -- rethrowing error
End Catch
```

Comment: @PostingQuestions, by not working, do you mean the error message is not returned as a result set like your original code? Why would you want to do that if the exception contains the same information?